# заполнение фрагментов в FragmentStatePagerAdapter

Tags: android, android-viewpager

Не где не могу найти ответ, сделал двойную навигацию с помощью navgationdrawer и viewpager теперь у меня есть табы и меню при переключении и свайпах все переключается корректно, могу размещать строку табов как мне нужно, но теперь не могу понять как заполнять фрагменты. делал по образцу [ссылка](http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/views/viewpager.php) переделал метод FragmentPagerAdapter в FragmentStatePagerAdapter

код адаптера CatPagerAdapter

```java
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.os.Bundle;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;

public class CatPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    private String[] mCatNames;
    private String[] mCatDescriptions;

    private final int[] mTopImageResourceIds = { R.drawable.cat_gold,
            R.drawable.cat_green, R.drawable.cat_white, R.drawable.cat_yellow };


    CatPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, Context context) {
        super(fm);

        Resources resources = context.getResources();
        mCatNames = resources.getStringArray(R.array.catsTitles);
        mCatDescriptions = resources.getStringArray(R.array.catDescriptions);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        Bundle arguments = new Bundle();
        arguments.putString(CatFragment.CAT_NAMES, mCatNames[position]);
        arguments.putString(CatFragment.CAT_DESCRIPTIONS,
                            mCatDescriptions[position]);
        arguments.putInt(CatFragment.TOP_IMAGE, mTopImageResourceIds[position]);

        CatFragment catsFragment = new CatFragment();
        catsFragment.setArguments(arguments);

        return catsFragment;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mCatNames.length;
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return mCatNames[position];
    }
}
```

код фрагмента CatFragment

```java
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;

public class CatFragment extends Fragment {
    static final String CAT_NAMES = "cats_names";
    static final String CAT_DESCRIPTIONS = "cat_descriptions";
    final static String TOP_IMAGE = "top image";

    public CatFragment() {
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_1, container, false);

        Bundle arguments = getArguments();
        if (arguments != null) {
            String catName = arguments.getString(CAT_NAMES);
            String catDescription = arguments.getString(CAT_DESCRIPTIONS);
            int topCardResourceId = arguments.getInt(TOP_IMAGE);

            displayValues(view, catName, catDescription, topCardResourceId);
        }
        return view;
    }

    private void displayValues(View v, String name,
                               String catDescription, int topCardResourceId) {
        TextView catNameTextView = v.findViewById(R.id.catTitle);
        TextView catDescriptionTextView = v.findViewById(R.id.catDescription);
        ImageView cardImageView = v.findViewById(R.id.topImage);

        catNameTextView.setText(name);
        catDescriptionTextView.setText(catDescription);

        cardImageView.setImageResource(topCardResourceId);
    }
}
```

разметка fragment_1.xml

```xml
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".CatFragment">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/catTitle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="Имя кота"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />


</LinearLayout>
```

код MainActivity

```java
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.TypedValue;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter;
import androidx.viewpager.widget.PagerTitleStrip;
import androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        CatPagerAdapter catPagerAdapter = new CatPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), this);

        ViewPager viewPager = findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        viewPager.setAdapter(catPagerAdapter);

        PagerTitleStrip pagerTitleStrip = findViewById(R.id.pager_title_strip);
        pagerTitleStrip.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 24);
        pagerTitleStrip.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);

        viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Выбран " + position,
                               Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Вопрос не очень ясен. Что значит `заполнять фрагменты`?

Comment: у меня есть 7 фрагментов при свайпе или перелистывании меняется фрагмент, но он пустой, в нем есть только полоса с табами. как я понял они заполняются динамически. я не совсем понимаю как их заполнять с готовых фрагментов или каждый фрагмент строится при его вызове

Comment: Всё ещё не очень ясно. У вас проблема с тем, что вы не знаете как во фрагмент поместить контент? Если да, то вам нужно в `onCreateView` инфлейтить разметку, наполнять её данными и возвращать из этого метода. Или у вас проблема с табами? Типа полоска табов есть, а вкладок в них нет? И если да, то не совсем ясно где эти табы - во фрагменте основном, во вложенных во ViewPager фрагментах или в активити? И с чем они связаны? С NavigationDrawer или с чем-то другим? У вас, кажется, очень сложная и необычная ситуация. Нужно много деталей и необходимый код.

Comment: проблема с тем как поместить контент в фрагмент

Comment: Тогда просто переопределите во фрагментах onCreateView создайте файл с разметкой для каждого фрагмента и всё

Comment: Предоставил код, вопрос как в CatPagerAdapter добавить еще несколько фрагментов с классами и разметкой. И сделать чтобы при свайпе фрагментов менялся таб, на соответствующий фрагменту, подскажите пожалуйста

Answer (score 0):

код MainActivity

```java
import android.os.Bundle;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager;

import com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Home"));
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("About"));
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Contact"));
        tabLayout.setTabGravity(TabLayout.GRAVITY_FILL);
        final ViewPager viewPager =(ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
        TabsAdapter tabsAdapter = new TabsAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), tabLayout.getTabCount());
        viewPager.setAdapter(tabsAdapter);
        viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));
        tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
            }
            @Override
            public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }
            @Override
            public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }
        });
    }
}
```

код адаптера TabsAdapter

```java
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter;

/**
 * Created by tutlane on 19-12-2017.
 */

public class TabsAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
    int mNumOfTabs;
    public TabsAdapter(FragmentManager fm, int NoofTabs){
        super(fm);
        this.mNumOfTabs = NoofTabs;
    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mNumOfTabs;
    }
    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position){
        switch (position){
            case 0:
                HomeFragment home = new HomeFragment();
                return home;
            case 1:
                AboutFragment about = new AboutFragment();
                return about;
            case 2:
                ContactFragment contact = new ContactFragment();
                return contact;
            default:
                return null;
        }
    }
}
```

код HomeFragment

```java
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;


/**
 * Created by tutlane on 09-01-2018.
 */

public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup viewGroup, Bundle savedInstanceState){
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.homelayout, viewGroup, false);
    }
}
```

другие фрагменты аналогичны

код файла homelayout

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:text="Homw Tab"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

код activity_main

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/main_layout"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:elevation="6dp" />

    <androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager

        android:id="@+id/view_pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</RelativeLayout>
```